# Angular component property inexplicably remains "undefined" after being set in subscribe()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-httpclient

Let me just preface this by saying **yes, i'm using arrow functions to retain the scope of "this"** (as far as I can tell anyway).

I have two properties on my component:

IsAdmin (boolean)
currentRole (string)

I make an api call to fetch user roles from my backend via Angular's HttpClient, and I have a callback subscribe-method which updates above mentioned properties with the result.

However, while I can assign the role value to currentRole, the other property IsAdmin remains undefined even as I assign it, and I get no error in my f12 debugger or visual studio code via the chrome plugin.

```
        import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
    import { AuthorizeService, IUser } from "../authorize.service";
    import { Observable } from "rxjs";
    import { map, tap } from "rxjs/operators";
    import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

    @Component({
      selector: "app-login-menu",
      templateUrl: "./login-menu.component.html",
      styleUrls: ["./login-menu.component.scss"]
    })
    export class LoginMenuComponent implements OnInit {
      isAuthenticated: Observable<boolean>;
      public userName: Observable<string>;

      IsAdmin : boolean;
      currentRole : string;

      constructor(private authorizeService: AuthorizeService, private http : HttpClient) {

      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.isAuthenticated = this.authorizeService.isAuthenticated();
        this.userName = this.authorizeService.getUser().pipe(map(u => u && u.name));
        const endpoint = '.../api/User/User/GetRoles';

        this.authorizeService.getUser()
          .subscribe(data => {
             this.userNameSignedIn = data.name;
          });

        this.http.get<string[]>(endpoint).
          subscribe(result => {
            this.currentRole = result[0];
            console.log("this.currentRole ", this.currentRole); //prints "admin"
            this.IsAdmin == result.includes("admin");
            console.log("this.IsAdmin", this.IsAdmin); //prints "undefined"
          }, error => console.error(error));
      }
    }
```

Console output is as following:

```
logon-menu.component.ts:37 this.currentRole  admin
logon-menu.component.ts:39 this.IsAdmin undefined
```

What on earth is going on here? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using ==

Comment: You're not assigning `this.IsAdmin` to `results.includes("admin")` correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem in your `subscribe` is that you are using `==`(comparison) instead of `=` (assignation)

```
          subscribe(result => {
            this.currentRole = result[0];
            console.log("this.currentRole ", this.currentRole); //prints "admin"
            this.IsAdmin == result.includes("admin"); //<-- here is an error
            console.log("this.IsAdmin", this.IsAdmin); //prints "undefined"
          },
```

your code should be:

```
          subscribe(result => {
            this.currentRole = result[0];
            this.IsAdmin = result.includes("admin");
          },
```

Comment: Oh my god. I don't know what to say. I've been looking at this problem for hours, trying everything and somehow i didn't see that. It's been a long day I guess.